# How to fix OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted (when opening file with sublime text 2)

Tags: permissions, installed-programs

After installing sublime text 2 using the following code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

(Slighlty relevant) I attempted to open a file and got a permissions error. After using chmod to get permission on the folder that was giving me issues, a new error occurred. (Only relevant because I'm not sure why this was a problem in the first place, so I'm not sure if it is related.)

After doing that and attempting to open any file (from the GUI) and I receive the following error:

Unable to run package setup:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./PackageSetup.py", line 165, in upgrade
    upgradePackage(pkg, pristinedir, datadir, backupdir)
  File "./PackageSetup.py", line 158, in upgradePackage
    os.path.join(backupdir, base), inhibitOverwrite)
  File "./PackageSetup.py", line 113, in upgradeArchive
    shutil.copy(src, dst)
  File ".\shutil.py", line 89, in copy
  File ".\shutil.py", line 66, in copymode
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/home/rubix/.config/sublime-text-2/Pristine Packages/AppleScript.sublime-package'
```

Any ideas as to what is going wrong/how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general when you have a file that give you this error, try from [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) next command:

```
sudo chown your_username:your_groupname filename
```

The groupname is usually just your username and filename, in your case case should be: `/home/rubix/.config/sublime-text-2/Pristine\ Packages/AppleScript.sublime-package`

Comment: After looking through the folder I found that all the files inside were all still zipped. I unzipped them as well as the did the chown... I'm guessing they did not need to be unzipped but I forgot to try it out in between so the world might never know :p. Thanks!